# Match each row using 3 columns conditions and return one last row only

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a merged excel file of multiple weekly orders files

```
import pandas as pd


Jan1 = pd.read_excel(r"~\Documents\1to6janReport1.xlsx")
Jan2 = pd.read_excel(r"~\Documents\7to12janReport2.xlsx")
Jan3 = pd.read_excel(r"~\Documents\13to19janReport3.xlsx")
Jan4 = pd.read_excel(r"~\Documents\20to26janReport4.xlsx")

all_df_list = [Jan1, Jan2, Jan3,Jan4]


appended_df = pd.concat(all_df_list)

appended_df.to_excel("SallesDB1.xlsx", index=False)
```

And the file structure look like this

What i want is to return a new dataframe to count the orders of each buyer.

Where if product equal product and buyer is not null and equal buyer return only the row where summary contain "product" and "ended".

I know it is complicated but I need to get the percentage of each buyer orders (counting the orders not quantity). The problem is that the same product will appear every day with summary of the day where a request can take a day or several days to end which would create inaccurate percentage.
Also after the order end of a buyer a new buyer can order the same product or the same buyer would start a new order and the only way to know that is using the summary (start , end ) as a key words.

The end result should be likes this

```
Product    date     quantity             summary                     buyer 
NO6      2/1/2019      6       Operation product request ended        KLW
ZS5      3/1/2019      5          The product request ended           WHM
```

Update

```
Product    date     quantity             summary                     buyer 
*day1*
AX1      2/1/2019      15     The product request started today       HTN
X5L      2/1/2019      0            No operation update               null
NO6      2/1/2019      6       Operation product request ended        KLW
ZS5      2/1/2019      5         The product request started          WHM
*day2*
AX1      3/1/2019      15        Product request still pending        HTN
X5L      3/1/2019      5         A new product request started        LKJ
NO6      3/1/2019      0           No update for operation            null
ZS5      3/1/2019      5          The product request ended           WHM
*day3*
AX1      4/1/2019      15            Product request ended            HTN
X5L      4/1/2019      5       The product request under-process      LKJ
NO6      4/1/2019      0           No update for operation            null
ZS5      4/1/2019      3      New request for the product started     KLW
```

So the data table (in excel) has over 200 products. These products will be repeated everyday. The summary for each product is different every day.

But what I really need is the buyer request number (count).

In product ***AX1*** for example the request started at the 2ed and ended at the 4th. Since I need the count of buyers I will need only one row where Product == Product and buyer == buyer, and summary contain both strings (product and ended).

Which is

```
Product    date     quantity             summary                     buyer 

AX1      4/1/2019      15            Product request ended            HTN
```

Again I know it is very complected.

Comment: Seems you could do this with an Excel formula, if that is acceptable. What would your above data show for results?

Comment: The end result should have the row where each operation end, I am not aware of a formula in excel that can preform that. please note that the file has  over 200 product and those are repeated for every day of the month

Comment: If you have `O365`, you can use the `FILTER` function.  Or, if you just want the count, you could use `COUNTIFS`

Comment: Well I know that could happen if you want a specific product and a specific company what i want is a list with all the filters applied to all the products

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean condition like this. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) Note in this code 'Nan' is just a string.

```
newdf= df[(df['buyer'] != 'Nan') 
           & df['summary'].str.contains('product')
           & df['summary'].str.contains('ended')
         ]
```

If Nan in `df['buyer']` is `None`, you can use `df.dropna()`.

---

**Edit**

To confirm df['Product'] have same value and df['buyer'] have same value, looped for all col items and concat only all-True.

```
p_items = pd.unique(df['Product'])
b_items = pd.unique(df['buyer'])

newdf = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Product', 'date', 'quantity', 'summary', 'buyer'])

for p_item in p_items:
    for b_item in b_items:
        tmp_df = df[
           (df['buyer'] != 'Nan')
           & (df['Product'] == p_item) 
           & (df['buyer'] == b_item)
           & df['summary'].str.contains('product')
           & df['summary'].str.contains('ended')]

        if len(tmp_df):
            newdf = pd.concat([newdf, tmp_df], sort=False)

print(newdf)
```

Comment: yeah Nan is null, It is a  great way to do it but how would it match the product name ? the product would be repeated every week

Comment: Match the product name, you mean, is like `df[df['Product'] == 'NO6'] `?

Comment: No I mean if product in row X equals product in row X1 and if so if buyer in the same row x equals buyer in x1 search summary for product and ended. Yup it is complected

Comment: I've edited to get same values for cols. This works for in/out you've provided. But not sure for large table, please try. And if not, please provide more table. Too small to understand  the all complicated conditions.

Comment: I updated my original question hope it is clear now

Comment: Thank you for updating. It seems I was missing upper case of 'Product'.  `df['summary'].str.contains('Product|product')` will work. Then please try from `df[df['summary'].str.contains('Product|product') &  df['summary'].str.contains('ended')]` ...